# Keeping a DataGridView autosorted

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I've got a `DataGridView` that is backed by a `SortableBindingList` [as described by this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx).

This is essentially a `BindingList` whose Data source is a list of custom objects.  The underlying custom objects are updated programatically.

My `SortableBindingList` allows me to sort each column in Ascending or Descending order.  I've done this by overloading the `ApplySortCore` method

```
protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
                                      ListSortDirection direction)
```

This works well for sorting when the column header is clicked on but won't sort automatically when cell in that column is programatically updated.

Has anyone else come up with a good solution for keeping a `DataGridView` sorted from programmatic updates of its underlying data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this class:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _value;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id"));
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            _value = value;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // optional code logic
    }
}
```

Add these methods to your sortable binding list:

```
public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where T : class
{
    public void Add(INotifyPropertyChanged item)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
        base.Add((T)item);
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(String.Format("{0}:{1}", sender, e)));
    }

    // other content in the method body
}
```

And use this sample methods in your form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    source = new SortableBindingList<MyClass>();
    source.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 1, Value = "one test" });
    source.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 2, Value = "second test" });
    source.Add(new MyClass() { Id = 3, Value = "another test" });
    source.PropertyChanged += source_PropertyChanged;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

}

void source_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.PropertyName);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MyClass)source[0]).Id++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to override OnDataSourceChanged Event

```
public class MyGrid : DataGridView {
    protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDataSourceChanged(e);
        MyComparer YourComparer = null;
        this.Sort(YourComparer);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I had tried this but it did not work for notifying me on all programmatic changes to the underlying DataSource